# How do I centre align div of fixed width which is middle div among 3 divs within parent div?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, responsive-design

This is my HTML (actually JSX) :
[image]

The middle div with class `domain-input-parent` should have fixed width of `400px` and should remain at centre of screen, horizontally

This way `domain-label` and `icon-container` will be of equal widths.

And this positioning should work for `any` screen width (>400px)

How can this be done ?

Following is the complete HTML:

```
  <div className="domain-container">
    <div className="domain-label">
      <p>Domain</p>
    </div>
    <div className="domain-input-parent">
      <input className="domain-input" id="website-url" placeholder="    https://www.yourwebsite.com" onInput={validateDomain} onClick={validateDomain}></input>
      <p id="error-text" className={ (hideErrorText == true) ? "hidden invalid-input" : "invalid-input"}>Please enter a valid domain ex. www.example.com</p>
    </div>
    <div className="icon-container">
      <img className="info-icon" src="images/info_icon.png"></img>
      <span className="tooltip-text">This is the top level website for seo radar to monitor.  We will validate the domain and will fetch the robots.txt file associated with it.  Examples: www.example.com or example.com.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Let me know if any other info is required.

Comment: Your question should include your existing CSS.

Comment: @BSMP yeah, right. main part was missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

input and img DO NOT have closing tags.  className is a JS construct.  Use flex

```css
.domain-container{
display:flex;

}

.y {width:400px}

.x {
width: calc((100% - 400px) / 2);
}

div{border:solid 1px black;}
```

```html
<div class="domain-container">
  <div class="domain-label x">
    <p>Domaina</p>
  </div>
  <div class="domain-input-parent y">
    <input className="domain-input" id="website-url" placeholder="    https://www.yourwebsite.com" onInput={validateDomain} onClick={validateDomain}>
    <p id="error-text" className={ (hideErrorText==t rue) ? "hidden invalid-input" : "invalid-input"}>Please enter a valid domain ex. www.example.com</p>
  </div>
  <div class="icon-container x">
    <img class="info-icon" src="images/info_icon.png">
    <span class="tooltip-text">This is the top level website for seo radar to monitor.  We will validate the domain and will fetch the robots.txt file associated with it.  Examples: www.example.com or example.com.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```